# Intellisense with Resource Dictionary in separate Assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution in vs2015 with two assemblies. One of them is a WPF application and the other is a WPF Class Library.

In My class library project root I have one `ResourceDictionary` called `Directory.xaml` - This has some styles, a few brushes and some strings etc.

Using:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Directory.xaml"/>
```

I can successfully use the resources, however I intend to use the compiled class library (dll) in future projects, the issue is, unless I import the project and reference that instead of just referencing the dll, I don't have any intellisense support.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I did not, sorry. It's been a long time since I worked with WPF so I doubt I'll likely ever solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone comes up with a better answer, but a workaround I decided upon was to use a class in the Library dll with the keys defined as const strings, using those defined strings in the dictionary, and then using the defined strings in the Application, where I get intellisense on the keys.

In the library dll, create a class that will have the resource keys defined:

```
public class KeyDefinitions {
  public const string Key1 = "key1";
  public const string Key2 = "key2";
}
```

Also in the library dll, in the resource dictionary, use those keys (sadly, I did not get Intellisense in the library's resource xaml file to detect members of KeyDefinitions):

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="{x:Static local:KeyDefinitions.Key1}" UriSource="../Images/Img1.bmp"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="{x:Static local:KeyDefinitions.Key2}" UriSource="../Images/Img2.bmp"/>
```

Then, in the Application, in the xaml, you can reference the keys from the KeyDefinitions class and get intellisense and compile-time checking on the keys:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Static myLibraryNamespace:KeyDefinitions.Key1}}" />
<Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Static myLibraryNamespace:KeyDefinitions.Key2}}" />
```

Of course, this assumes you have control over the Library dll!